# Looks like an Exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException is ignored

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have a problem with exceptions: the code I use is:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub KiesPad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles KiesPad.Click
    Dim dlg As New FolderBrowserDialog
    Dim result As DialogResult = dlg.ShowDialog()
    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each f As String In IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dlg.SelectedPath, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Try
                Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile(f, FixName(f))
                Me.RichTextBox1.Text = Me.RichTextBox1.Text & "Aangepast " & f & " in " & FixName(f) & vbCrLf
            Catch ex As System.UnauthorizedAccessException
                MsgBox("Security problem")
            Catch ex As IO.IOException
                'Bestandsnaam niet aangepast. Bestaat al, niks doen.
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message & ex.HResult)
            End Try
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

When this code is run, I get an error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: no access fot c:\users\jack\documents\pictures`
```

But I did a catch exception for `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You don't catch exceptions when calling `IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries`. Move your `Try` block higher:

```
Try
    For Each f As String In IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dlg.SelectedPath, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile(f, FixName(f))
            Me.RichTextBox1.Text = Me.RichTextBox1.Text & "Aangepast " & f & " in " & FixName(f) & vbCrLf
    Next
Catch ex As System.UnauthorizedAccessException
    MsgBox("Security problem")
Catch ex As IO.IOException
    'Bestandsnaam niet aangepast. Bestaat al, niks doen.
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & ex.HResult)
End Try
```